# Melhor forma de dar binding em objetos de 1 para N - asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, .net

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de dar o *Binding* de dados no objeto `FuncaoGrupo` do meu `Controller`. Cada item da lista `Funcoes` irá gerar 4 `Checkbox` na View.

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
public class GrupoDeUsuario
{
    public GrupoDeUsuario()
    {
        Funcoes = new HashSet<FuncaoGrupo>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int GrupoDeUsuarioId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(length: 100, ErrorMessage = "Descrição do grupo deve ser somente 100 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Descrição do Grupo de Usuário deve ser informada")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FuncaoGrupo> Funcoes { get; set; }

}
```

> Obs: Consegui fazer mas foi utilizando `FormCollection`, porém gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira melhor ou correta de se fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma é passando o grupo de usuário novamente para a *Action* `POST`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Salvar(GrupoDeUsuario grupoDeUsuario)
{
    /* Lógica de negócios aqui */
}
```

Possivelmente seu problema de *binding* está relacionado ao fato de que o `ModelBinder` não envia os valores de cada função ligada ao grupo de usuário de volta para o *Controller*. Pra que isso aconteça, é preciso ter duas coisas no seu `form`:

1. Cada registro de função precisa ser identificado com um índice;
2. Os campos de cada função devem ser indexados pelo valor contido neste campo de índice.

Em resumo, o índice de uma função é um `<input type="hidden">` em qualquer lugar do formulário cujo name é `Funcoes.index` e valor um inteiro ou `Guid`. Para simplificar, eu vou usar inteiros:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Funcoes.index" value="1" />
```

Agora, os campos `checkbox`. Você não disse seus nomes, então vou chamá-los de `Campo1`, `Campo2`, `Campo3`, `Campo4`. Ficaria assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Funcoes.index" id="Funcoes_index" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Funcoes[1].Campo1" id="Funcoes_1_Campo1" value />
<input type="checkbox" name="Funcoes[1].Campo2" id="Funcoes_1_Campo2" value />
<input type="checkbox" name="Funcoes[1].Campo3" id="Funcoes_1_Campo3" value />
<input type="checkbox" name="Funcoes[1].Campo4" id="Funcoes_1_Campo4" value />
```

Apenas isto já é suficiente para que a *Action* reconheça os valores ao enviar o formulário. Só que isto é um tanto prolixo de fazer, então é melhor usar uma ferramenta pra isso. No caso, o nome dela é [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). [Já respondi várias e várias vezes sobre ela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+begincollectionitem). O que ela faz é gerar este campo de índice e indexar os campos pra você, mas ela funciona bem usando Razor. Ficaria assim:

```
@foreach (var funcao in Model.Funcoes)
{
    using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Funcoes"))
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(_ => funcao.Campo1)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(_ => funcao.Campo2)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(_ => funcao.Campo3)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(_ => funcao.Campo4)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um EditorFor para sua coleção de Funcoes, sem ter que utilizar o FormCollection. Você consegue fazer isso com "for", com foreach nao vai funcionar, já aviso. Sua View seria mais ou menos assim:

```
@model SeuProjeto.GrupoDeUsuario

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao)

@for(int i = 0; i < model.Funcoes.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Funcoes[i].DescricaoFuncao)
}
```

Seu controller seria mais ou menos assim:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   GrupoDeUsuario grupo = dbContext.GrupoDeUsuario.Include(g => g.Funcoes).FirstOrDefault();

   return View(grupo);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(GrupoDeUsuario grupo)
{
  // aqui voce tem o grupo, com suas funcoes preenchidas, sem usar form collection
}
```